# SELinux, Fedora, and Trusted Applet crashing?

Tags: java, linux, applet, selinux

For some reason, if I run Firefox 3.5.x under Fedora 11 with SELinux enabled, my browser crashes when I attempt to embed the applet dynamically. Under Windows, Ubuntu, and Mac, the user is prompted to trust the signer and then trust the executing java applet, but under Fedora, I never see this prompt. If I disable SELinux, I get NO prompting, and the applet embeds without any notice whatsoever!

Remembering that trusted applets can execute user programs and manipulate user data, this becomes quite a nightmare. Has anyone else had to deal with SELinux and Fedora/SuSE/Linux  and trusted applets before? If so, how did you overcome this broken behavior?

Comment: Are you kidding me? Superuser? It's my damned applet, and I'm having issues deploying it under restrictive end environments. I need a PROGRAMMATIC solution to this problem, or I'm pretty much screwed.

Comment: "if I run Fedora 3.5.x under Fedora 11" Presumably you meant Firefox in place of one of those words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dynamically embed the applet, you'll get crashing. Instead, use an iframe to load the applet inline and make your event trigger the changing of the iframe src.